# PostCSS, missing semicolon after generating new rule

Tags: css, postcss

I'm experiencing this issue twice.

First when i remove the last item of a rule, and when i create a new one.
As you can see, the final bracket is out of place, and the final semicolon is nowhere to be found.

Kindly point out what i'm missing, or show me where in the API docs i can find more info for this behaviour.

```
import * as postcss from 'postcss';

export default postcss.plugin('...', (options = {}) => {
    return root => {

        root.walkRules(rules => {

              const atrule = rules.nodes.filter(node => {
                return (node.type === 'atrule' && node.name === 'add');
              });

              if (atrule.length === 1){

                const params = atrule[0].params.split(' ');

                const position = params[0];
                const radius = (params[1] === 'circle' ? '100%' : '0');
                const color = params[2];
                const side = params[3];
                const dimensions = params[4];

                rules.removeChild(atrule[0]);

                const decl1 = postcss.decl({ prop: 'content', value: '" "' });
                const decl2 = postcss.decl({ prop: 'border-radius', value: radius });
                const decl3 = postcss.decl({ prop: 'width', value: dimensions +'px' });
                const decl4 = postcss.decl({ prop: 'height', value: dimensions +'px'});
                const decl5 = postcss.decl({ prop: 'border', value: side + 'px solid ' + color });

                const new_rule = postcss.rule({ selector: rules.selector + ':' + position });
                new_rule.append(decl1, decl2, decl3,decl4,decl5);

                root.append(new_rule);



              }   
        });
    };
});
```

my output is the following

```
#test{
  background-color : red}
#test:before{
  content : " ";
  border-radius : 100%;
  width : 15px;
  height : 15px;
  border : 1px solid blue}
```

Comment: In CSS, a semicolon is a separator, not a terminator; So the last one before the `}` is optional, and I presume that postcss omits it for that reason. Poor man's minimising. It is not an error and will not cause problems.

Comment: Oh, thank you, thought it was a mistake.